# Popular inputs com arquivo Json em jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Gostaria de saber como faço para preencher alguns inputs através de dados de um arquivo json com jQuery.

Segue os dados em Json:

```
{"data":[
{"id":"0","lNeg":"","cnpjToma":"02.558.157/1001-62","nDoc":"00121961","nPed":"5100484612","dtEmis":"01/11/2016","dtVenc":"01/01/2017","munic":"SÃO PAULO","codNat":"17.06","opts":"","tipoDoc":"","vIcms":"","vDoc":"","irrf":"","inss":"","iss":"","pis":"","cofins":"","cssl":"","Obs":""},
{"id":"1","lNeg":"","cnpjToma":"20.558.756/1232-01","nDoc":"23463546","nPed":"1234979878","dtEmis":"23/01/2016","dtVenc":"25/10/2017","munic":"CAMPINAS","codNat":"12.01","opts":"","tipoDoc":"","vIcms":"","vDoc":"","irrf":"","inss":"","iss":"","pis":"","cofins":"","cssl":"","Obs":""},
{"id":"2","lNeg":"","cnpjToma":"09.333.000/1000-89","nDoc":"98984776","nPed":"7896563535","dtEmis":"09/05/2016","dtVenc":"19/12/2017","munic":"INDAIATUBA","codNat":"14.56","opts":"","tipoDoc":"","vIcms":"","vDoc":"","irrf":"","inss":"","iss":"","pis":"","cofins":"","cssl":"","Obs":""},
{"id":"3","lNeg":"","cnpjToma":"43.115.201/1203-79","nDoc":"24984333","nPed":"4676563531","dtEmis":"08/03/2016","dtVenc":"10/05/2017","munic":"SALTO","codNat":"01.99","opts":"","tipoDoc":"","vIcms":"","vDoc":"","irrf":"","inss":"","iss":"","pis":"","cofins":"","cssl":"","Obs":""},
{"id":"4","lNeg":"","cnpjToma":"11.551.151/1011-62","nDoc":"10121962","nPed":"9900484743","dtEmis":"11/11/2016","dtVenc":"02/03/2017","munic":"ITU","codNat":"13.06","opts":"","tipoDoc":"","vIcms":"","vDoc":"","irrf":"","inss":"","iss":"","pis":"","cofins":"","cssl":"","Obs":""}          
]}
```

Segue os inputs em html:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="cnpjToma">CNPJ tomador:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnpjToma" name="cnpjToma">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="nDoc">N° do docum:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nDoc">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="nPed" class="text-danger">N° do pedido:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nPed">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="dtEmis">Data de emissão:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dtEmis">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="dtVenc">Data de vencim:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dtVenc">
</div>
```

Segue o jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var dados;
    $.ajax({
        url: "detalhes.json",
        success: function(data){
            dados = data;
        }
    });

var populateInputs = function(data){
    for (var prop in data){
        var val = data[prop];
            $("#" + prop).val(val);
    };
};
    populateInputs(dados[0]);
  })
```

Comment: Onde se encontra este arquivo JSON? Você precisará fazer uma requisição ao servidor para lê-lo.

Comment: No diretório raiz mesmo do projeto, na minha máquina.

Comment: Os dados em `data` formam um array. É preciso indicar exatamente como você quer fazer esse preenchimento. Não dá pra inserir todos esses dados separados e ao mesmo tempo nesses mesmos campos.

Comment: @Bruuno Vianna E se no caso eu retirar os colchetes funcionaria? Pois seria objetos dentro do objeto data.

Comment: Você tem um problema de regra aqui. Por exemplo, pra cada cnpjToma que você tem no objeto json, você tem apenas um correspondente no seu formulário. Eu já preparei um código que resolve a questão, mas preciso de mais detalhes de como exatamente você quer preencher.

Comment: Por exemplo: você pode pegar apenas um id nesse objeto e popular os dados. Assim, cada campo terá um valor dentro de um id.
Outro exemplo: você pode varrer todos os ids em data e popular o formulário. Só que isso vai deixar os campos com os dados apenas do ultimo id, já que os anteriores serão normalmente substituídos.

Comment: O problema não é a estrutura dos dados, mas como você quer popular esse formulário tendos vários dados possíveis pra somente um campo correspondente. Entende?

Comment: @BrunnoVianna Então precisaria de uma condição para mostrar conforme o id dos objetos Json, se for id 0 preenche os campos com os dados do objeto 0 e assim por diante.

Comment: Sim, igual apresentado abaixo...

Comment: @Leandro Veja minha resposta e, qualquer dúvida, pode me chamar.

Comment: Ok BrunoVianna vou testar aqui e te dou um feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, faça uma requisição ao arquivo json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "nomeDoArquivo.json",
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

Salve os dados em algum outro local:

```
var dados;
$.ajax({
    url: "nomeDoArquivo.json",
    success: function(data){
        dados = data;
    }
});
```

Depois, criar uma função para percorrer os campos em dados e popular os campos do formulário:

```
var populateInputs = function(data){
    for (var prop in data){
        var val = data[prop];
        $("#"+prop).val(val);
    };
};
```

Então, é só usar:

```
populateInputs(dados[0]);
```

Uma dica importante: Seu arquivo original está mal formatado. Por exemplo, em `{"id:"0"` não está sendo fechado as aspas em id. Outro problema, é que ele abre um novo objeto `{"lNeg"` sem uma vírgula antes. Isso vai dar erro de parse.

Altere para:

```
{"data":[
    {"id":"0", "lNeg":"",...}
```

Comment: @BrunnoViana o meu aqui não deu certo cara. Formatei o Json igual ao seu. No console mostra o erro: *Cannot read property '0' of undefined*.

Comment: Imprime o conteúdo do objeto que você está passando pra dentro de populateInputs, por favor, e cola pra eu ver.

Comment: desculpa cara não entendi. Não domino Json. no caso aí seria

Comment: `{"id":"0","lNeg":"","cnpjToma":"02.558.157/1001-62","nDoc":"00121961","nPed":"5100484612","dtEmis":"01/11/2016","dtVenc":"01/01/2017","munic":"SÃO PAULO","codNat":"17.06","opts":"","tipoDoc":"","vIcms":"","vDoc":"","irrf":"","inss":"","iss":"","pis":"","cofins":"","cssl":"","Obs":""},`

Comment: por favor cara não me abandona :) quando invoco a variável `populateInputs(dados[0]);` fora de `function(data)` ela da o erro **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**, mas quando chamo dentro da função não da erro no console, mas, tbm não popula os inputs;

Comment: Você gravou a resposta do ajax numa variável externa como indique? Veja no meu código que eu iniciei uma variável global `dados` e, dentro do ajax, eu atribuí ela a dados, assim: `dados = data`.

Comment: sim, editei a pergunta e coloquei o seu script ali.

Comment: @Leandro Você consegue disponibilizar o código em algum lugar? Acho que você está chamando populateInputs antes do retorno da chamada do ajax. Precisamos ver o tempo de execução da sua aplicação.

Comment: O jquery está ali na pergunta pouco mais acima, chamei onde vc demonstrou.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65317/discussion-between-brunno-vianna-and-leandro).

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso, pega o Objeto por id e utiliza os atributos dele para colocar nos inputs da seguinte forma:

```
$("#cnpjToma").val(objeto[0].cnpjToma)
```

Em js puro:

```
document.getElementById("cnpjToma").value = objeto[0].cnpjToma
```

Só que isso vai tornar seu código um pouco estático, se quiser fazer dinâmico ou utilizar todos os objetos do array terá que criar uma lógica para percorrê-lo e utilizar os atributos destes.

Mas é basicamente isso ai, o resto é lógica sua!

Abraço!

Comment: Ele espera uma solução usando jQuery, como descrito na pergunta.

Comment: Ok, mas jQuery = javascript, é só utilizar o que facilita do jQuery e pronto.

Comment: Pronto agora como jquery.

Comment: Desculpe, mas ainda não é assim. Deveria ser `$("#cnpjToma").val(objeto[0].cnpjToma)`

Comment: Tudo bem, eu desconheço de jQuery, mas esse tipo de questionamento pode ser resolvido com js puro, e para quem conhece jQuery é só converter. E eu não prefiro dar respostas prontas, gosto que a pessoas olhem uma dica e busquem conhecimento para poderem fixar o conhecimento. Mas fica ao cargo de cada um né. valeu

Comment: Alias, usei do seu comentário para arrumar o código :) valeu pela dica.

Comment: Eu concordo com você. Usar js puro nesse caso seria muito melhor. Porém, estou seguindo as regras do SO em respeitar a solicitação da pergunta. Você poderia sugerir o uso do javascript puro como uma solução melhor ao solicitado. ;)

Comment: Agora ficou legal!